# Get nodes having more than X relationships and it's children in specific format

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this Cypher query:

```
MATCH (Parent)-[R1]-(Child)
MATCH (Child)-[R2]-(Grandchild)
WHERE ID(Parent)=238777 
RETURN Parent, Child, type(R1) as R, count(R2) as Degree
```

Which returns data in this format:

```
Parent | Child | Relationship name | Degree of child (how many relationship child has)
```

What I'd like to do now is to find all nodes which have more than X relationships and display results in the same format.

What I currently have is this query:

```
MATCH (Parent:FullAddress)-[r]-(Child)
MATCH (Child)-[R2]-(Grandchild)
WITH Parent, count(r) as childrenCount, collect(Child) as ChildrenList, r
WHERE childrenCount > 10
UNWIND ChildrenList as ChildrenSeparate
RETURN Parent, ChildrenSeparate, type(r)
```

Which returns data in this format:

```
Parent | Child | Relationship name
```

Any suggestions on how to add `degree` functionality?

Comment: Degree of the child node?

Comment: Yes, degree of child node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a library called APOC (Awesome Procedures on Cypher) and it has tons of really cool function. One of them is `degree` function.

Check this out if you're running into similar issues. It simplified my queries a lot!